# Html template use on golang

Tags: html, http, go, go-html-template

Sorry im beginner and i read golang.docs but didnt understand well.
i`ve :   index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action type="checkbox" name="test" value="A" {{.checked}}>
<input type="submit" value="save">
</body>
</html>
```

in main.go
   if user click save button then check checkbox redirect that page and show checkbox checked

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: how to set value to {{.checked}}

Comment: You should edit your post and write what you have done so far and where you have problems. Otherwise we are unable to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send variables in map. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    t, _ := template.New("hi").Parse("Hi {{.name}}")
    var doc bytes.Buffer
    t.Execute(&doc, map[string]string{"name": "Peter"})
    fmt.Println(doc.String()) //Hi Peter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.` is defined in go code.

Please provide the snippet of your go code where the template is executed, something like the following codes:

```
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles(tmpl + ".html")
    t.Execute(w, data) // the data must feature the field "checked"
```

Or

```
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl+".html", data) // the data must feature the field "checked"
```

You can pass any type(interface{}) to a functions that execute a template as "data". Usually it is a Struct or a Map[string]string.

**How to set the checked**
Probably the "checked" is setted in the main.go at handler according to the posted form.

Read the docs and explain it better. Please