# How to use html with golang

Tags: html, templates, go

I am learning golang and trying to make a simple website. This is my folder structure.

```
- ui
   |
   - login.html
- cmd
   |
   - main.go
```

My `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var tmpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("../ui/login.html"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", foo)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func foo(reswt http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(reswt, "../ui/login.html", nil)

}
```

`login.html`

```
<html>
    <form method="POST">
        <label for="uname">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="username">
        <br>

        <input type="submit">

    </form>
</html>
```

When I executre `main.go`, I do not get errors. But nothing on `localhost:8080`.

If I keep `main.go` and `login.html` same folder, this works.

Why this folder structure is not working? I have tried [this SO thread], but this is not solving my problem[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597162/html-template-use-on-golang)

Following parts added after `css` is not working.

```
<style>
input[type=submit]:active {
  background: #cde5ef;
  border-color: #9eb9c2 #b3c0c8 #b4ccce;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

</style>


<div class="login">
  <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p class="remember_me">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
        Remember me on this computer
      </label>
    </p>
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="login-help">
  <p>Forgot your password? <a href="#">Click here to reset it</a>.</p>
</div>
```

When I go to `localhost:8080`

I get following output in my browser.

```
<style> input[type=submit]:active {   background: #cde5ef;   border-color: #9eb9c2 #b3c0c8 #b4ccce;   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);   box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0,
0.2); } } </style>


<div class="login">   <h1>Login to Web App</h1>   <form method="post" action="">
    <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <p class="remember_me">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
        Remember me on this computer
      </label>
    </p>
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>   </form> </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ParseFiles` stores the names of the list of files as **template name**. That means, in your case, `login.html` should be used in the execution, while `../ui/login.html` is unavailable.

---

This would work, as login.html has already been named by `init()`.

```golang
func init() {
    tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("../ui/login.html"))
}

func foo(reswt http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(reswt, "login.html", nil)
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate how to do it? explain with details please.. as I am golang beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can Call like this for Generic type

```
import(
"html/template"
)
```

```
// output html
func OutputHTML(w http.ResponseWriter, filename string, data interface{}) {
   t, err := template.ParseFiles(filename)
   if err != nil {
       http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
       return
   }
   if err := t.Execute(w, data); err != nil {
       http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
       return
   }
}
```

And you call this like

```
OutputHTML(w, "anyhtmlfile.html",nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the generic answer. I have an another issue, when I post `html`, style doesnt get parsed. Everything is printed as a row `html` page.

Comment: Can't understand your problem add your sample code here for better help.